# SQL Injection - Enconding

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I would like to clarify a question that I have, if my page request to the database with your charset is set to UTF-8, and the response of the request to the database is in ISO-8859-2/LATIN1 this causes a opening for sql injection, how could this be?

Example:

search.php ---- declaring the encoding in html header (Content-Type: text / html; charset = utf-8)

make a request in my MySQL database (Server charset: Latin1 (ISO-8859-1))

search.php? id = blablabla

answer:

search_results.php --- declaring the encoding in html header (Content-Type: text / html; charset = utf-8)

Note that the encoding of MySQL database is different from the page that will display the result, search_results.php, what will prevail is the database, right? This causes a gap to SQL Injection because certain characters may differ from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8, and also as an example to other encodings.

Comment: No, my question is different.

Comment: It is. But its intent is also mostly incomprehensible. If it's not entirely based on presumptions, elaborate with an example.

Comment: Ok, i wrote an example.

Comment: it could be great question if you provide proper example

Comment: A more precise example.